# SQL Server Business Intelligence Studio: Discontinuous Line Chart

Tags: visual-studio-2008, rdl, report-designer

I have a report in SQL Server Business Intelligence Studio that is a .rdl file(Report Definition/Report Designer). Currently, the report graphs a line chart given the a LOAN_AMOUNT(Y-AXIS) for a given Day of the Month (X-AXIS). Everyday of the month is not represented as data being retrieved from the database. As a result, certain parts of a line may be discontinuous. How do I make this line continuous even if no data-points exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a function like this:

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=61519

To generate all dates, even if they are not in the database and assign the loan amount to 0.

For instance, if in february (no leap year) and your database has values for feb 1, and feb 14 only then you should use the date function posted to get all dates and assign the value 0 to loan amount of all other dates.  Only then should you use this as your datasource for your report (I assume you are using stored procedures and not a direct table).

Comment: Jon, thanks so much for the quick response! Actually, the data is coming directly from a database table. No stored procedures to my knowledge. Is there a way to tell visual studio to somehow interpolate the lines in a way that they are continuous?

Comment: @dionysus - you should never use direct tables when you create reports.  It defeats the purpose of filters, parameters, etc.  You should base your report on that table but using a stored procedure.  That way you can mimic and play with the results to get the desired results.  In your case, you would write a stored procedure and fill in the missing dates.

Comment: @JonH - Thanks once again for your advice! I'll see what I can do about this.

Comment: @dionysus - if you developed the report or can edit it I recommend going the stored procedure route.  Then you can manipulate the data a little bit.  For instance, you can pull that data from the database table that you have and join it to the DATE FUNCTION I posted in the link and give it a date range like Feb 1 - Feb 28 or whatever date range you want.  Then for any dates that are not in your table just set the LOAN_AMOUNT_VALUE from your database to 0.  That way your graph is continous.

Comment: @JonH- Does the date range have to be within one month only are can it be over a series of months. Say from August to December?

Comment: @dionysus - can be anything even yearly :)